# Mysql intersection of two subsets

Tags: mysql, intersection, subset

I'm wondering if anyone can help me to solve the problem that I meet. :)
I have a table with articles, named `article` and also I have a table `commonarticletechnique`  where I save all the techniques that can be used by reporters to compose an article. Also I have a table `articletechnique` where I have references between articles and common articles techniques. Sorry for my english, I'm not a native english speaker. So my situation looks like:

`Article`(`Id`,`Many other fields...`)

`CommonArticleTechnique`(`Id`, `Name`, `Description`)

`ArticleTechnique`(`Id`, `FkArticleId`, `FkCommonArticleTechnique`)

For example I can have in tables things like:

- in `article` an article with id 282;
- in `commonarticletechnique` all kind of techniques used by users to write an article;
- in `articletechnique` i can have

1, 282, 12

2, 282, 13

3, 282, 14

So, with these records, I can say that article with id 282 have 3 techniques of conception.

In UI I have a section where users can search in my database and they can check none, one, ore more article techniques. So if I want to find an article that is based on techniques 12, 13, 14 I have to write an mysql query to get all the articles that are matching `exactly` with my techniques.

In my example if user select 12, 13 techniques, mysql shouldn't return the article 282.
In this case the problem that rises up is bounded by the intersection of two mysql subsets.
One of them is from a collection extracted from a table and the other subset is from UI, from what's the selection of users.

Please tell me if know how to write the mysql query and also it is very helpfully to not implement a stored procedure.

Thanks for all,
Aryliah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose there can't be two entries on same article with same technique (two times 282, 12 for example). Which also mean you don't *need* an Id PK in your articletechnique table.

Anyway.

Your query should be something like this :

```
SELECT t1.FkArticleId
FROM ArticleTechnique t1
WHERE t1.fkArticleId IN (SELECT t2.FkArticleId
                         FROM ArticleTechnique t2
                         WHERE t2.FkCommonArticleTechnique IN (12, 13))
GROUP BY t1.FkArticleId
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

of course, `x` in `HAVING COUNT(*) = x` must be equal to the number of techniques selected (12, 13 are... 2 techniques in this case)

Comment: Thanx Raphael, your answer satisfied my problem. You suppose very well. My hope was to write a query with a single parameter, but in this case, it looks very simple and your query is very clear. I appreciate your help! Thank you again!